# How to add keyboard shortcut for custom nemo action?

Tags: cinnamon

I have an custom nemo action as explained here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nemo#Nemo_Actions

How can I add an shortcut for this action?

(If it can be done adding a line in `~/.gnome2/accels/nemo`, then I have the additional problem that on my system this file is auto generated on every reboot, so editing something here will not help. I have Cinnamon 3.2.7 and nemo 3.2.2.)

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 5):

**Nemo Action**

First, you should place the `myaction.nemo_action` under `~/.local/share/nemo/actions/`.

Then, to make a keystroke put an underscore `_` in front of the letter you want. For example in the `Hello _Shortcut` the `s` is the key. So you press the right-click and then `s`.

Bellow is an example of my action to open files and directories with Atom:

```
# Custom action for Nemo File Manager for Cinnamon.
# Adds right-click open file/files or directory with Atom.
# Place it under: ~/.local/share/nemo/actions/atom.nemo_action
# For more info: https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/files/usr/share/nemo/actions/sample.nemo_action

[Nemo Action]
Active=true
Name=Open in _Atom
Comment=Open %F in Atom
Exec=atom %F
Icon-Name=atom
Selection=any
Extensions=any;
Dependencies=atom;
Quote=double
```

**Global Shortcut**

If you want a global shortcut, you should use the Cinnamon `Keyboard` setting under the `System settings`, go to the second tab and add your custom shortcut.
Or, if you prefer more control over CLI you can use the `dconf`. For example, the bellow configuration will add the shortcut `Shift><Alt>a`

```
/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/name
  'Open Atom'
/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/command
  'atom'
/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/binding
  ['<Shift><Alt>a']
/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-list
  ['custom0']
```

Comment: Is there any way without needing the extra right-clicking and menu navigation?  I don't want to just find the item in the menu quickly - that's not that useful.  Instead I want to select files, and then just press a keyboard shortcut, and have it be as though I right clicked and clicked on the action.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Am trying to respond to Duncan Marshall but the post ended up in the mainthread. Yes, it's possible. Your file ~/.gnome2/accels/nemo can contain a line such as the following, which would execute a scrip file named edit.sh when F4 is pressed. The scripfile must be located in this special path (~/.local/share/nemo/scripts) and it must be enabled via a checkbox in User Interface>Edit>Preferences>Plugins>Scripts. Also i was unable to specify a script path such as ~/... instead of /home/username... When the syntax in the accels/nemo file is incorrect, nemo will prepend the incorrect line with ; and it will also delete the keycode at the end of the line and it also likes to resort lines in the accels file. I will also dismiss a line when the keycode was already used in another line. So it couldn't be more tricky to get this right.

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ScriptsGroup/script_file:\\s\\s\\shome\\sUSERNAME\\s.local\\sshare\\snemo\\sscripts\\sedit.sh" "F4")
```

the script file might look like this

```
#!/bin/bash
export FILETOEDIT="$1"
FILEOWNER=$(stat -c %U "$1")
if [ "$FILEOWNER" = "$USER" ]; then
  subl "$1"
else
  sudo xed -w "$FILETOEDIT"
fi
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Scripts have to be inside a *special* directory, and yet their absolute path should be used for defining associated shortcuts! :| Stupid design?